# Testing Android application on real phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

I am running into countless problems with the emulators of different versions. Sometimes it loads, othertimes it hangs, I've tried reinstalling the SDK and platforms etc. Even though I've a reasonably a high-end machine, when I manage to get it working performance is very slow.
Therefore, I'm thinking of buying a real phone to test out on. If I do so, can I get away with buying one second hand without bill-plans, SIM card etc? I only want it to test out on, I don't want to get stuck with bills for something I don't need to use.

Any advice is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you're in the US, you can get a phone from Cricket for ~$100 - no plan, no contract, nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I gave up the emulators a long time ago. As you are saying, it's slow.

If you want to get away cheap buy a "LG Optimus One P500", you can get it for ~150EUR. But it all depends on what version of Android you wanna develop for. No SIM or other fancy stuff is needed.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check andoid x86 project http://www.android-x86.org/ You can find some instructions on the web how to get it working with ADB.

Comment: Just had a look at this site, but not sure what this achieves, is it some sort of alternative to the emulator? Excuse my ignorance

Comment: It is actually a port of android for x86 systems, you can run it smoothly in a virtual machine and then connect it to ADT. And yes, you can use this as an alternative to the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

I would say you get a Droid Incredible, cheap but I think its one of the best and cheapest Droids out. But yes the emulator is horrible, I have to use my own phone to test.

Get a phone from Cricket you don't need a plan from there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any Android phone you buy for testing without having a contract. Without a contract, you won't get phone service or 3G/4G, but everything else will work just fine. You can buy one used or at full retail from a provider. Just don't activate a service plan.

Comment: btw, I agree the emulator is horribly slow. It won't even run on my machine.